# Error en pool de conexiones Jboss - Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle-11g, jboss-as-7

tengo la siguiente situación:
Tengo una base de datos `Oracle 11g`, un usuario de conexión a la misma el cual el `profile` al que pertenece tiene configurado el número de `sessions` en `UNLIMITED`

En el servidor de aplicaciones tengo un `JBoss 7 AS` con un pool de conexiones de `x` conexiones máximas.

El tema es que las  `x` conexiones en el `JBoss` se usan en su totalidad y presenta errores que no puede administrar más conexiones, entonces aumento el número de conexiones en el pool pero al aumentarlas `Oracle` empieza a rechazar las conexiones

Que puedo hacer, donde deberia realizar los ajustes??

Comment: Tiene pinta de que la gestion de conexiones no es correcta y se quedan abiertas.

Comment: ¿Qué frameworks o librerías usas en tu aplicación? Hay una pregunta similar en SO donde el problema resultó ser Hibernate, que no devolvía las conexiones al pool tras usarlas y por tanto el gestor nunca las consideraba *desocupadas*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645435/database-connections-not-closed-after-idle-timeout-in-wildfly-datasource

Comment: Si, algo me he sospechado del tema, precisamente se esta usando Hibernate, revisare la configuración que mencionan en el enlace y os voy contando. Muchas gracias